# How to create an installer for an application that uses 'Martincostello.Sqllocaldb', without having reference problems?

Tags: c#, android, vb.net, nuget

I have tried handling SQLLocalDB with 'https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb' and it works fine, but when I try to package the application to install it on another machine, it has not been possible, not even with the Visual Studio 2017-2019 installer, nor with InstallShield 2020, since they always find reference problems.

Does anyone here have or know where to locate an example setup project, using either 'Martincostello.Sqllocaldb' or some other similar resource, to make the application able to be moved from one computer to another, to work with SQLLocalDB?

For example, when the installer is being built with InstallShield 2020, it always gives a warning that it can't find the SNI.dll or some of its references. But during the installation of 'Martincostello.Sqllocaldb' with NuGet, a folder named 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.1.0.19235.1' was created and inside it, there are several sub folders where those files can be located, i.e. , SNI.dll.

Answer (score 0):

put the missing .dll to the resources of your project and on startup of the project, check if the instalation path is consist of specific file like SNI.dll if it doesn't exit then include it manually using code

```
    If Not IO.File.Exists("SNI.dll") Then
        IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath & "\SNI.dll", My.Resources.SNI)
    End If
```